# What should I read to see what happened with Ms Marvel during the Secret Wars?

Tags: marvel, comics, suggested-order, ms-marvel

I just picked up the Ms Marvel TPB Vol 5 (Super Famous), which I was disappointed to discover does not pick up directly after Vol 4 (Last Days). Although, I am happy to see the series continue, obviously.

If I understand correctly, this is mainly covered by the Secret Wars story arc. [The Secret Wars TPB](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_Wars_(2015_comic_book)) looks like it requires quite a bit of additional continuity knowledge to follow - can anyone recommend a minimal set of books to fill in the gaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For most Marvel characters coming out of the *SECRET WARS* event, nothing during the event is relevant after it. There are multiple versions of most of the characters, and nothing that happens to them carries forward when we return to normal.

The exceptions are the handful of characters who haven't returned to "reality" yet, and the characters who came from different Earths. The first group is primarily the Richards family (they'll be back eventually, *FANTASTIC FOUR* can't stay gone forever). The second group includes Old Man Logan, Miles Morales, and Red Wolf.

I believe Ms Marvel makes appearances in *INHUMANS: ATTILAN RISING* and *A-FORCE* (and maybe in *SECRET WARS: SECRET LOVE* - I didn't get that one), but she wasn't a major character, and nothing there is relevant to your v 5 trade.

As you noted, coming back, she has become a member of

> The (All-New, All-Different) Avengers.

Basically, post-Secret-Wars, all the books picked up several (8, I think) months after where they'd left off. From what I've read since, only major events from that time period will be revealed. Thus far (to the best of my knowledge), the only event that has been revealed is the discovery of the impact of terrigen mists on the mutant population (in *DEATH OF X*).

Unlike when DC did something similar years ago ("One Year Later", after *INFINITE CRISIS*), there has been no announcement of a series (like DC's *52*) to cover what happened during these "missing" months.

In this case, I suspect Marvel mostly wanted to avoid the confusion of dealing with what people did or didn't remember out of *SECRET WARS*, especially when the time came to deal with those characters who did get moved into the "regular" Marvel U. It seems logical that, if anything else of real significance happened, it will eventually be dealt with. Otherwise, we should assume that things happened in an unremarkable way. As with that other book: Ms. M (and the other two youngsters affected) had existing connections that could logically lead to an invitation to join up and be trained, without the need for some unknown major storyline to bring it about.

Comment: Is it the case then, that this is an intended gap in knowledge that will actually be addressed in the Ms Marvel comic itself?