# What is the story containing the "incursion zone" event from Ms. Marvel (2014) #17

Tags: story-identification, marvel, comics, ms-marvel

I just finished the 2014 *Ms. Marvel* series.

In issue #17, Captain Marvel tells Kamala that the strange, red planet-like thing in the sky of Manhattan is an "incursion zone", and, in the following issue (#18), Carol Danvers left Kamala to go take care of it

I'm looking for the series/issue/event to find out where Captain Marvel went and why.

[image: Kamala and Captain Marvel talking about the incursion zone]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue is part of [Ms. Marvel Vol. 4: Last Days](https://www.marvel.com/comics/collection/52246/ms_marvel_vol_4_last_days_tpb_trade_paperback). The incursions/ white events that Carol refers to are part of the [Avengers: Time Runs Out](https://www.marvel.com/comics/discover/370/avengers-time-runs-out) story-line.

> The incursion is actually a parallel Earth. Once the two Earths collide, both Earths as well as both universes that they belong to will be destroyed. By this point, the Illuminati have failed to come up with a permanent solution to the problem and the rest of Earth's heroes have become aware of it.

If you want to continue following the story from this point, you could start with [Secret Wars: Last Days](https://www.marvel.com/comics/discover/536/secret-wars-last-days). If you want to back up for a bit more context, you may consider reading Hickman's [Infinity](https://www.marvel.com/comics/events/315/infinity).

Comment: As far as Ms. Marvel's story, see my [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/158928/80867) to a related question. Basically, she appears in one or more of the _Secret Wars_ stories, but those amount to alternate reality versions of her. Simply move on to her next on-going, and her appearances in _All-New, All-Different Avengers_ and _Champions_.